# ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on MODIFY column command

Tags: mysql

I need to modify my primary key column. I want to change int to bigint. but there is an error. How can I change it? I don't want to delete keys..

```
ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN itemnumber bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

> ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './kohadata/#sql-3ae3_5cf5' to
>   './kohadata/items' (errno: 150)

My table;

```
 CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `itemnumber` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `biblionumber` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (`itemnumber`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483647 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complications could occur because of the auto_increment and primary key attributes.
How about doing it in two phases :

1. remove the primary key (ALTER TABLE items  MODIFY COLUMN itemnumber bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY;)
2. add the primary key again (ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN itemnumber bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;)

Or as I have just read, it might be because foreign key constraints. You need to remove foreign key constraints in other tables that refer to this table, change the primary key in items table, change the column type in other tables to match the new column type, and re-add the foreign key constraints.